# Two topology questions regarding quotient $D^n/S^{n-1}$ and homotopy $S^{n-1} \to S^{n} - \{ a,b\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I got two simple questions.

1. Why is $D^n/S^{n-1} = S^n$? If we are quotienting out the boundary, the interior isn't empty.
2. The two spaces $S^{n-1}$ and $S^{n} - \{ a,b\}$ where $a,b$ are north/south pole of n-sphere are supposed to be homotopic. What is the homotopic map? I can never come up with these maps on my own. Are there some techniques to these?

All I ever can start is $u = (x/|x|)$ and think of some clever projection. $(u_1,\dots,u_{n-1}) \to (u_1,\dots, u_{n-1},?)$ Are most of these maps that involve $S^n$ just some clever application of stereographic projection?

Comment: Does in $D^n$ you mean the closed disc? ($\bar{D_n} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| \le 1\}) $

Comment: @dan yeah. unit disk. It was just an excerpt of something I read in Hatcher. It just looked right, but I couldn't justify it in my head.

Comment: I am sorry for not having a formal answer, but for part 1 - I think of $\bar{D_n} / \partial \bar{D}^n$ as $D^n \cup {p}$ when $p\in \partial \bar{D}^n$ now the stereographic projection gives you $S^n \setminus\{point\} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n $ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to the open disc $D^n$ so we got homeomorphism from $S^n\setminus \{point\}$ to $D^n$ . Now take your one boundary point (which represnt $\partial \bar{D}^n$) and define $point \mapsto boundary point$ this gives the wished homemorphism.

Comment: So basically you are saying $S^n/\{x\} = S^n/\{p\} = D^n$ and adjoining the point $\{p \}$ means $D^n/S^{n-1}= D^n \cup p = S^n$. Is there actually a difference between $\bar{D}$ and $D$ in your notation?

Comment: Yes because $\bar{D}$ includes the boundary $\partial \bar{D}^n$ , $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to $D^n$ but not to $\bar{D}^n$.

Comment: I would suggest starting with $n=2$ so you can visualize the spaces. The formulas you come up with should generalize.

Comment: @dan, sorry I am confused, the closed disk is its own closure right?

Comment: Here's a way to think about the disk case: think of the disk as the (closed) upper hemisphere of $S^n$. Now slide the equator to the South Pole. This is just mapping the boundary of the disk to the South Pole, and mapping the interior of the disk to the rest via stereographic projection.

Comment: For the punctured sphere case, imagine flattening your sphere (by dropping the last coordinate). Now normalize. The first part can be done as a homotopy.

Comment: I just realized it is $(x,y,z) \to (x,y)/\sqrt{1-z^2}$

Answer (score 0):

We write $S^n = \{ (x,r) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \mid \lVert x \rVert^2 + r^2 = 1 \}$, where $\lVert - \rVert$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

Question 1:

Define
$$p : D^n \to S^n, p(x) = 
\begin{cases}
(\dfrac{\sqrt{1 - (1 - 2\lVert x \rVert)^2}}{\lVert x \rVert}x, 1-2\lVert x \rVert) & x \ne 0 \\
(0,1) & x = 0
\end{cases}
 $$
This is well-defined because $1-2\lVert x \rVert \in [-1,1]$ and
$$\left\lVert \dfrac{\sqrt{1 - (1 - 2\lVert x \rVert)^2}}{\lVert x \rVert}x \right\rVert^2 + (1-2\lVert x \rVert)^2 = 1 - (1 - 2\lVert x \rVert)^2 + (1-2\lVert x \rVert)^2 = 1 .$$
$p$ is continuous  because for $x \to 0$ we get $\left\lVert \dfrac{\sqrt{1 - (1 - 2\lVert x \rVert)^2}}{\lVert x \rVert}x \right\rVert = \sqrt{1 - (1 - 2\lVert x \rVert)^2} \to 0$.

For $x \in S^{n-1}$ we have $p(x) = (0,-1) = b$.

Next define
$$j : S^n \setminus \{b\} \to int(D^n) = D^n \setminus S^{n-1}, j(y,r) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1 - r}{2\sqrt{1- r^2}}y & y \ne a = (0,1) \\
0 & y = a = (0,1)
\end{cases}
$$
This is well-defined because
$$\left\lVert \dfrac{1 - r}{2\sqrt{1- r^2}}y \right\rVert = \dfrac{1 - r}{2\sqrt{1- r^2}}\left\lVert y \right\rVert = \dfrac{1 - r}{2} < 1 .$$
It is easily verified that $p(j(y,r)) = (y,r)$ for all $(y,r)$ and $j(p(x)) = x$ for all $x \in int(D^n)$. Hence $p$ maps $int(D^n)$ bijectively onto $S^n \setminus \{b\}$.

$D^n , S^n$ are compact Hausdorff, hence $p$ is a closed map and thus a quotient map (aka identification map).  By the above considerations there exists a unique function $h : D^n/S^{n-1} \to S^n$ such that $h \circ \pi = p$, and it is a bijection. By the universal property of quotient maps we see that both $h$ and $h^{-1}$ are continuous, i.e. $h$ is a homeomorphism.

Question 2:

Define
$$i : S^{n-1} \to S^n \setminus \{a,b\}, i(x) = (x,0) ,$$
$$g : S^n \setminus \{a,b\} \to S^{n-1}, g(x,r) = \dfrac{x}{\lVert x \rVert} .$$
For $g$ note that $\lVert x \rVert \ne 0$ because $x \ne a, b$, i.e. $r \in (-1,1)$. We have $g \circ i = id$. Next define
$$H : (S^n \setminus \{a,b\}) \times [0,1] \to  S^n \setminus \{a,b\}, H(x,r,t) = (\sqrt{\dfrac{1 - t^2r^2}{1- r^2}} x,tr) .$$
This is well-defined because
$$\left\lVert \sqrt{\dfrac{1 - t^2r^2}{1- r^2}} x \right\rVert^2 + (tr)^2 = \dfrac{1 - t^2r^2}{1- r^2} \lVert x \rVert^2 + t^2r^2 = \\ \dfrac{1 - t^2r^2}{1- r^2} (1 - r^2) + t^2r^2 = 1 .$$
We have $H(x,r,1) = (x,r), H(x,r,0) = (\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1- r^2}},0) =(\dfrac{x}{\lVert x \rVert},0) = (i \circ g)(x,r)$, that is $i \circ g \simeq id$.

This means that $S^n \setminus \{a,b\}$ and $S^{n-1}$ are homotopy equivalent.

More precisely, $i$ embeds $S^{n-1}$ as a strong deformation retract into $S^n \setminus \{a,b\}$ because we have $H(x,0,t) = (x,0)$ for all $t$.