Homotopy groups and explicit description of the comultiplication on the $n$-sphere
My question is motivated by Inverse of a homotopy class in the $n$-th homotopy group where one can find a definition of the multiplication in the homotopy group $\pi_n(Y,y_0)$. The linked question shows that this definition is a bit unclear. Also see Question 2 below.
It is well-known that the reduced suspension $S(X,x_0)$ of a pointed topological space $(X,x_0)$ is a cogroup object in the homotopy category $\mathbf{hTop_0}$ of pointed pointed topological spaces.
With $J = [-1,1]$ we have
$$S(X,x_0) = (X \times J)/(X \times \{-1,1\} \cup \{x_0\} \times J) $$
which is a pointed space (the basepoint $*$ is the common equivalence class of the points of $X \times \{-1,1\} \cup \{x_0\} \times J$).
A comultiplication $\kappa : S(X,x_0) \to S(X,x_0) \vee S(X,x_0)$ is defined by
$$\kappa([x,t])= \begin{cases} ([x,2t+1],*) & t \le 0 \\ (*,[x,2t-1]) & t \ge 0 \end{cases} \tag{1}$$
Note the wedge of two pointed spaces $(A,a_0)$ and $(B,b_0)$ can be represented as the pointed subspace
$$(A,a_0) \vee (B,b_0) = (A \times \{b_0\} \cup \{a_0\} \times B, (a_0,b_0))$$
of $A \times B$.
The idea to construct $\kappa$ is to collapse $X \times \{0\} \subset S(X,x_0)$ to a point which produces a one-point union of two "smaller" copies of $S(X,x_0)$. Identifying them with $S(X,x_0)$ gives a canonical homeomorphism $h : S(X,x_0)/(X \times \{0\}) \to S(X,x_0) \vee S(X,x_0)$. Then $\kappa = h \circ q$, where $q$ is the quotient map.
The comultiplication $\kappa$ induces a group structure on the set $[S(X,x_0),(Y,y_0)]_*$ of pointed homotopy classes of pointed maps $S(X,x_0) \to (Y,y_0)$ to an arbitrary pointed space $(Y,y_0)$. Explicitly
$$[f] \cdot [g] = [\phi \circ (f \vee g) \circ \kappa]$$
where $\phi : (Y,y_0) \vee (Y,y_0) \to (Y,y_0)$ is the canonical folding map.
We can rewrite this in the form $[f] \cdot [g] = [f \cdot g]$ with
$$(f \cdot g)([x,t]) = \begin{cases} f([x,2t+1]) & t \le 0 \\ g([x,2t-1]) & t \ge 0 \end{cases} \tag{2}$$
This is a succint and clear formula.
The pointed $n$-sphere $(S^n,*)$ can be identified with the reduced suspension $S(S^{n-1},*)$. Thus $(S^n,*)$ is a cogroup object in $\mathbf{hTop_0}$ so that we get the $n$-th homotopy group
$$\pi_n(Y,y_0) = [(S^n,*), (Y,y_0)]_* .$$
Question 1: I have never seen an explicit formula like $(2)$ above for $f \cdot g$ with $f, g : (S^n,*) \to (Y,y_0)$. Is there any reference in the literature for such a formula? Equivalently one could exhibit an explicit comultiplication on $(S^n,*)$ resembling $(1)$.
One may argue such an explicit formula is not really needed, but it would be nice to have one. One could do it by writing down an explicit homeomorphism $\iota  :(S^n,*) \to S(S^{n-1},*)$, but this seems to be tedious. It seems obvious that such $\iota$ should be the identity on the equator $S^{n-1} \times \{0\}$ and map the upper / lower
hemisphere of $S^n$ to the upper / lower reduced cone in $S(S^{n-1},*)$. Thus the desired comultiplication on $(S^n,*)$ will collaps the equator of $S^n$ to a point and identify the quotients of the upper / lower hemisphere by the equator with $(S^n,*)$.
Question 2: In Inverse of a homotopy class in the $n$-th homotopy group one can find a definition of type $(2)$, but it is not completely explicit because it uses the fact that maps $f : (S^n,*) \to (Y,y_0)$ can be regarded as maps of pairs $f' : (B^n,S^{n-1}) \to (Y,y_0)$ via an unspecified quotient map $(B^n,S^{n-1}) \to (S^n,*)$. Anyway, it is a nice approach. But there is something I do not understand. Formula $(2)$ appears to be "symmetric" for $f, g$, but the $g$-part in the formula in Inverse of a homotopy class in the $n$-th homotopy group includes an involution on $B^n$, whereas the $f$-part does not. Why is the involution needed? Is it correct at all?

Two pointers: 1. An (indeed tedious) formula for $\iota$ can be found in George W. Whitehead, Elements of Homotopy Theory, p. 107. 2. The projection $p$ in the linked post induces homeomorphisms of either hemi-sphere with the unit disk, but one of them is orientation-preserving and the other -reversing (and which is which depends on the parity of $n$), so that is why $i$ might appear (I have not double-checked whether the formula in that post is correct, to be clear, but these orientation questions are generally the only difficulty in getting a correct formula down).

I agree to your remark that an explicit formula for $S^n$ is not really needed. Nevertheless let us discuss your questions.
Question 1
The problem is that $S^n$ is an object with a geometric structure: It is the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with respect to the Euclidean norm. One could also take any other norm and consider the unit sphere with respect this norm, but this does not make an essential difference because all these unit spheres are canonically homeomorphic geometric objects. In contrast a reduced suspension $S(X,x_0)$ does not have any relevant geometric structure which makes it easy to define the comultiplication in a purely formal way. Defining a comultiplication on $S^n$ requires much more effort because we have to take care that the geometric structure is preserved.
Concerning references: I do not know any. However, as you write, one could use an explicit homeomorphism $h : S(S^{n-1},*) \to (S^n,*)$ to get a comultiplication. As Thorgott comments, such a homeomorphism is constructed on p.107 in

Whitehead, George W. Elements of homotopy theory. Vol. 61. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

Actually Whitehead does not construct precisely a homeomorphism $S(S^{n-1},*) \to (S^n,*)$; he inductively constructs homeomorphisms $S^{n-1}(I/\partial I,*) \to (S^n,*)$ where $S^{n-1}$ denotes $(n-1)$-fold reduced suspension. His method could be adjusted to obtain the desired homeomorphism $h$.
For the sake of completeness we shall later construct an explicit homeomorphism which seems to be different from Whitehead's.
As a preparation let us now consider the comultiplication on $S(X,x_0)$. As you write in your question, the lower cone $C_-(X,x_0)$ = image of $X \times [-1,0]$ under the projection $X \times J \to S(X,x_0)$ is mapped to $S(X,x_0)$ by collapsing $X \times \{0\}$ to a point. Similarly the upper cone $C_+(X,x_0)$ = image of $X \times [0,1]$ under the projection $X \times J \to S(X,x_0)$ is mapped to $S(X,x_0)$. This gives maps $\kappa_\pm : C_\pm(X,x_0) \to S(X,x_0)$ which can be pasted to $\kappa : S(X,x_0) \to S(X,x_0) \vee S(X,x_0)$.
The maps $\kappa_\pm$ are not independent. To see this, let $i : S(X,x_0) \to S(X,x_0), i([x,t]) = [x,-t]$ be the obvious involution on $S(X,x_0)$. It restricts to a homeomorphism $i_+ : C_+(X,x_0) \to C_-(X,x_0)$. It is easy to verify that
$$\kappa_+ = i \circ \kappa_- \circ i_+ . \tag{0}$$
For the desired comultiplication on $S^n$ we have to specify first a basepoint. We take $* = (1,0\ldots,0)$. Let $i : S^n \to S^n, i(x_0,\ldots,x_n) =  (x_0,\ldots,-x_n)$, be the involution exchanging north and south pole, and let $S^n_-, S^n_+$ be the lower and upper hemisphere, respectively. The desired comultiplication will be specified by a suitable map
$$\kappa_- : S^n_- \to S^n$$
which collapses the equator $S^{n-1}_0 = S^{n-1} \times \{0\}$ to $*$. The corresponding map $\kappa_+: S^n_+ \to S^n$ will be determined formally by $(0)$, but of course it also has a direct "geometric" interpretation.
Let $\pi_\pm : S^n_\pm \to D^n = \{ x \in \mathbb  R^n \mid \lVert x \rVert \le 1\}$ denote the projections omitting the last coordinate. They are homeomorphisms. In my answer to Equivalence between two homotopy groups definition I constructed a quotient map $p : D^n \to S^n$ such that $p(S^{n-1}) = \{*\} , p(0) = (-1,0,\ldots, 0)$ which maps $D^n \setminus S^{n-1}$ homemorphically onto $S^n \setminus \{*\}$. Here it is:
$$p : D^n \to S^n, p(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\left(2\lVert x \rVert -1, \dfrac{\sqrt{1 - (2\lVert x \rVert -1)^2}}{\lVert x \rVert}x \right) & x \ne 0 \\
(-1,0, \ldots,0) & x = 0
\end{cases}
 $$
I also gave a "geometric interpretation" what $p$ does. Now take
$$\kappa_- = p \circ \pi_- . \tag{1}$$
Translating the geometric interpretation of $p$ to $\kappa_-$ results in this:
Imagine $S^n_-$ as a rubber skin sitting on the sphere $S^n$ and tack it at $*$. Let $C_\pm \subset S^n$ be the semicircle containing the three points $(-1,0,\ldots, 0)$, $(0, \ldots,0,\pm 1)$ and $*$. Then grab the rubber skin at the point $(-1,0,\ldots, 0)$ and pull it over $S^n$ along $C_+$ from $(-1,0,\ldots, 0)$ to $*$. This "clockwise" deformation of the rubber skin keeps all points of it on $S^n$, keeps $*$ fixed and collapses $S^{n-1}_0$ to $*$.
As explained above, we have
$$\kappa_+ = i \circ \kappa_- \circ i_+ = i \circ p \circ \pi_- \circ i_+  = i \circ p \circ \pi_+ . \tag{2}$$
The geometric interpretation of $\kappa_+$ is therefore this:
Imagine $S^n_+$ as a rubber skin sitting on the sphere $S^n$ and tack it at $*$. Grab the rubber skin at the point $(-1,0,\ldots, 0)$ and pull it over $S^n$ along $C_-$ from $(-1,0,\ldots, 0)$ to $*$. This "counterclockwise" deformation of the rubber skin keeps all points of it on $S^n$, keeps $*$ fixed and collapses $S^{n-1}_0$ to $*$.
We have now explicitly shown what $\kappa : (S^n,*) \to (S^n,*) \vee (S^n,*)$ looks like. But again: I think we do not really need it.
Question 2
The exposition in Inverse of a homotopy class in the $n$-th homotopy group is a bit unclean because it does not take care of the basepoint. However, the above considerations already answered Question 2. Our map $p$ can be taken as the "unspecified quotient map $(D^n,S^{n-1}) \to  (S^n,*)$" in your Question 2. It explains the origin of the involution $i$ in $(2)$.
Update
The question arose whether the approach in Inverse of a homotopy class in the $n$-th homotopy group (involution on $D^n$ followed by $p$) and our above approach ($p$ followed by involution on $S^n$) agree, i.e. if $i \circ p = p \circ i$ with $i : D^n  \to D^n, i(x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}) = (x_0,\ldots,x_{n-2},-x_{n-1})$.
This is fact true. One can easily check it by using the explicit formula for $p$ in my answer to Equivalence between two homotopy groups definition. If one understands the "geometric interpretation" what $p$ does, then it is also intuitively clear.
Note that in Inverse of a homotopy class in the $n$-th homotopy group the involution on $D^n$ is performed with the first coordinate. This is, however, related to the different choices of basepoints. Up to homotopy it does not make a difference anyway.
Appendix: Construction of a homeomorphism $h : S(S^{n-1},*) \to (S^n,*)$.
We have to be precise concerning basepoints. Let us agree to take $e^k = (1,0,\ldots, 0)$ as the basepoint of $S^k$.
We shall construct a quotient map
$$q : S^{n-1} \times J  \to S^n$$
collapsing $T = S^{n-1} \times \{-1,1\} \cup \{e^{n-1}\} \times J$ to $e^n$ and mapping $T^\complement = (S^{n-1} \times J) \setminus T = (S^{n-1} \setminus \{e^{n-1}\}) \times (-1,1)$ bijectively onto $S^n \setminus \{e^n\}$. The map $q$ clearly induces a homeomorphism
$$h : S(S^{n-1},e^{n-1}) \to (S^n,e^n) .$$
To understand the idea, we need some notation. Let $j : S^{n-1} \to S^n, j(x) = (x,0)$, denote the canonical equatorial embedding (which is an isometry), $s = (0,\ldots,0,-1)$ denote the south pole of $S^n$ and for $x \ne e^{n-1}$ let $C'_x$ denote the circle with center $0$ and radius $r(x)  = \frac{\lVert e^{n-1} - x \rVert}{2} = \frac{\lVert e^{n} - j(x) \rVert}{2}$ in the two-dimensional subspace $R_x \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ spanned by $d(x) = e^n - j(x)$ and $s$. Note that $\lVert d(x) \rVert = 2 r(x)$. Let $c(x) = \frac{e^n + j(x)}{2}$ and $C_x = c(x) + C'_x$. The set $C_x$ is a circle in the affine plane $E_x \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ obtained from $C'_n$ by the translation $y \mapsto c(x) + y$. By definition $j(x) = c(x) - \frac{d(x)}{2}$ and $e^n  = c(x) + \frac{d(x)}{2}$ lie in $C_x$.
For $x \ne e^{n-1}$ the map $q$ will wrap $\{x\} \times J$ around the circle $C_x$. The formal definition  is
$$q(x,t) = \begin{cases} c(x) + r(x)(\cos(\pi(t+1))\frac{d(x)}{\lVert d(x) \rVert} + \sin(\pi (t+1))  s) & x \ne e^{n-1} \\ e^n & x = e^{n-1} \end{cases}. $$
Let us  check that this makes sense.

$q(x,t) \in S^n$, i.e. $\lVert q(x,t) \rVert^2 = 1$.

This is trivial for $x = e^{n-1}$. For $x \ne e^{n-1}$ observe that the three vectors $c(x), d(x), s$ are orthogonal (the inner product of any two distinct of them is $0$). Thus
$$\lVert q(x,t) \rVert^2 = \lVert c(x) \rVert^2 + \left\lVert r(x)(\cos(\pi(t+1))\frac{d(x)}{\lVert d(x) \rVert}  \right\rVert^2 + \lVert r(x)\sin(\pi (t+1))s \rVert^2 $$
$$= \lVert c(x) \rVert^2 + r(x)^2\cos^2(\pi(t+1)) + r(x)^2\sin^2(\pi(t+1)) = \lVert c(x) \rVert^2 + r(x)^2 = 1 .$$
Concerning the last step observe that $\lVert j(x) + e^n) \rVert^2 = \lVert j(x) \rVert^2 + 2j(x) \cdot e^n + \lVert e^n \rVert^2 = 2 +  2j(x) \cdot e^n$ and similarly $\lVert j(x)- e^n \rVert^2 = 2 - 2j(x)\cdot e^n$.

$q$ is continuous.

Only the continuity in the points $(e^{n-1},t_0)$ has to be checked. The diameter of $C_x$ is $2r(x)$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Hence for $\lVert x - e^{n-1} \rVert < \epsilon$  the diameter of $C_x$ is $ < \epsilon$, therefore $C_x$ is contained in the open $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $e^n = q(e^{n-1},t_0)$ in $S^n$. Since $q(x,t)  \in C_x$, we are done.

$q(T) = \{e^n\}$.

By definition $q(e^{n-1},t) = e^n$. For $t = \pm 1$ we have $\cos(\pi(t+1)) = 1$ and $\sin(\pi(t+1)) = 0$, thus
$$q(x,\pm 1) = c(x) + r(x) \frac{d(x)}{\lVert d(x) \rVert} = c(x) + \frac{e^n - j(x)}{2} = e^n .$$

$q$ maps $T^\complement$ bijectively onto $S^n \setminus \{e^n\}$. Note that this implies that $q$ is surjective.

$q$ maps $\{x\} \times (-1,1)$ bijectively onto $C_x^* = C_x \setminus \{e^n\}$ for all $x \ne e^{n-1}$. The $C_x^*$ are pairwise disjoint, thus $q$ is injective on $T^\complement$.  We claim that $\bigcup_{x \ne e^{n-1}} C_x = S^n$ which shows that $q(T^\complement) = \bigcup_{x \ne e^{n-1}} C_x^* = S^n \setminus \{e^n\}$.
Let $\pi : S^n \to D^n$ denote the projection omitting the last coordinate. For $x \ne e^{n-1}$ let $L_x = \pi(C_x)$. This set is the line segment connecting $e^{n-1}$ and $x$. It is clear that $\pi^{-1}(L_x) = C_x$ (let $c_0(x) = \frac{e^{n-1}+x}{2}$, $d_0(x) = e^{n-1} - x$ and note that all points of $S^n$ which are mapped by $\pi$ to $q'(x,t) = c_0(x) + r(x)\cos(\pi(t+1))\frac{d_0(x)}{\lVert d(x) \rVert} \in L_x$ must have last coordinate $\pm \sqrt{ 1- q'(x)^2}$ which shows that they lie on $C_x$). But $\bigcup_{x \ne e^{n-1}} L_x = D^n$, thus $S^n = \pi^{-1}(D^n) = \pi^{-1}(\bigcup_{x \ne e^{n-1}} L_x) = \bigcup_{x \ne e^{n-1}}\pi^{-1}(L_x) = \bigcup_{x \ne e^{n-1}} C_x$.
The homeomorphism $h : S(S^{n-1},e^{n-1}) \to (S^n,e^n)$ has the following properties:

It is the identity on $S^{n-1}_0$. For $x \ne e^{n-1}$ this follows from $h([x,0]) = q(x,0) =  c(x) - r(x)\frac{d(x)}{\lVert d(x) \rVert} = c(x) -  \frac{d(x)}{2} = j(x) = (x,0)$.

It maps $C_\pm(S^{n-1},e^{n-1})$ homeomorphically onto $S^n_\pm$. In fact, for $x \ne e^{n-1}$ and $t \ge 0$ we have $\sin(\pi(t+1)) \le 0$ so that the last coordinate of $h([x,t]) = q(x,t)$ is $\ge 0$. The case $t \le 0$ is similar.


Remark. The second property is the reason why we used the south pole $s$ in the definition of $q$. This choice has a little price: The parameterization of the circle $C_x$ is made clockwise. For the "standard" counterclockwise parameterization one has to replace $s$ by the north pole of $S^n$.
Using $h$, we can define $\kappa_- : S^n_- \to S^n$ as the mapping making the following diagram commutative:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C_-(S^{n-1},e^{n-1})\ @>{h_-}>> S^n_- \\
@V{\kappa_-}VV @VV{\kappa_-}V \\
C(S^{n-1},e^{n-1})\ @>{h}>> S^n
\end{CD}
This means that $\kappa_-$ "stretches" each lower half-circle $(C_x)_-$ clockwise to $C_x$ by moving the point $h([x,t]) \in S^n_-$ to $h([x,2t+1])$. This is nothing else than our above heuristic "rubber skin move".
Let us also compute $h^{-1}$. Clearly $h^{-1}(e^n) = *$. Given $\xi =(\xi_0,\ldots, \xi_n) \in S^n \setminus \{e^n\}$, we have to find $(x,t) = (x(\xi),t(\xi)) \in T^\complement$ with $h([x,t]) = q(x,t) = \xi$.
The point $x$ is the intersection point of the ray starting at $e^{n-1}$ and going through $\pi(\xi)$ with $S^{n-1}$. Thus we have to solve
$$\lVert e^{n-1} + \tau(\pi(\xi)- e^{n-1}) \rVert^2 = 1.$$
The left hand side is $1 + 2\tau e^{n-1}\cdot (\pi(\xi)- e^{n-1}) + \tau^2\lVert \pi(\xi) - e^{n-1} \rVert^2$ so that we get
$$2\tau e^{n-1}\cdot (\pi(\xi)- e^{n-1}) + \tau^2\lVert \pi(\xi) - e^{n-1} \rVert^2 = 0 .$$
Solutions are $\tau_0 = 0$ and $\tau_1 = 2\frac{1 - e^{n-1}\cdot \pi(\xi)}{\lVert \pi(\xi) - e^{n-1} \rVert^2}$. The desired intersection point is obtained for $\tau = \tau_1$, thus we get
$$x = x(\xi) = e^{n-1} + 2\frac{1 - e^{n-1}\cdot \pi(\xi)}{\lVert \pi(\xi) - e^{n-1} \rVert^2}(\pi(\xi)- e^{n-1}) .$$
To determine $t$ we have to solve
$$j(\pi(\xi)) =  c(x) + r(x)\cos(\pi(t+1))\frac{d(x)}{\lVert d(x) \rVert} = c(x) + \cos(\pi(t+1))\frac{d(x)}{2}$$
which means
$$\cos(\pi(t+1))d(x) = 2(j(\pi(\xi)) - c(x)) .$$
With the above functions $c_0, d_0$ we can get rid of $j$ and obtain
$$\cos(\pi(t+1))d_0(x) = 2(\pi(\xi)) - c_0(x)) .$$
Writing $\pi(\xi) = e^{n-1} + \theta(\xi) (x - e^{n-1})$ we get
$$\theta(\xi) = \frac{\lVert \pi(\xi) - e^{n-1} \rVert}{\lVert x - e^{n-1} \rVert} .$$
If $\theta(\xi) \le \frac 1 2$, then $\pi(\xi)$ lies on the line segment between $e^{n-1}$ and $c_0(x)$. If $\theta(\xi) \ge \frac 1 2$, then $\pi(\xi)$ lies on the line segment between $c_0(x)$ and $x$.
Looking at the parameterization of $C_x$, we get
$$t = t(\xi) = \begin{cases} \frac 1 \pi \arccos\left(2\frac{\lVert \pi(\xi) - c_0(x) \rVert}{\lVert d_0(x)\rVert}\right) - 1 & \xi \in S^n_-, \theta(\xi) \le \frac 1 2 \\ \frac 1 \pi \arccos\left(-2\frac{\lVert \pi(\xi) - c_0(x) \rVert}{\lVert d_0(x)\rVert}\right) - 1 & \xi \in S^n_-, \theta(\xi) \ge \frac 1 2 \\ -\frac 1 \pi \arccos\left(2\frac{\lVert \pi(\xi)) - c_0(x) \rVert}{\lVert d_0(x)\rVert}\right) + 1 & \xi \in S^n_+, \theta(\xi) \le \frac 1 2 \\ -\frac 1 \pi \arccos\left(-2\frac{\lVert \pi(\xi)) - c_0(x) \rVert}{\lVert d_0(x)\rVert}\right) + 1 & \xi \in S^n_+, \theta(\xi) \ge \frac 1 2 \end{cases}$$
Altervatively we can determine $t$ by solving
$$\xi_n = -r(x)\sin(\pi(t+1)).$$
This yields
$$t = t(\xi) = \begin{cases} -\frac 1 \pi \arcsin\left(\frac{\xi_n}{r(x)}\right) - 1 & \xi \in S^n_-, \theta(\xi) \le \frac 1 2 \\  \frac 1 \pi \arcsin\left(\frac{\xi_n}{r(x)}\right) & \theta(\xi) \ge \frac 1 2  \\ -\frac 1 \pi \arcsin\left(\frac{\xi_n}{r(x)}\right) + 1 & \xi \in S^n_+, \theta(\xi) \le \frac 1 2 \end{cases} $$
Based on the above computations it is of course possible to write down an explicit formula for $\kappa_-$, but this seems to be complicated and not enlightening.

Thank you for your answer. I have one more question concerning the involution. You make the involution on $S^n$, but in the question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4746813/349785 the involution is made on $B^n$. Doesn't it make a difference?
